# Scroll physics with listview in Custom area - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to set,
user can scroll and see the admins --- inside red marked container (look at the picture).

- "Admins" Text don't want to scroll
- Listtiles in ListView.Builder only scroll inside red area marked in picture (red area = Container)

my try here :

```
              Container(
                    height: 300,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const CustomText(
                              align: TextAlign.start,
                              size: 20,
                              text: "Admins",
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                        ListView.builder(
                          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: itlength,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 5, vertical: 10),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(name),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text(sub),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap your `ListView.builder` with `Expanded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your `ListView` with `Expanded` to take all the available space will fix it but **make sure that the parent of the container is Column not a Scrolling widget**.